# using modelformset_factory and placeholder

Tags: python, django

I am using modelformset_factory.

how do I add a placeholder text in each form field generated?

for example, I have

AdvisorsFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        S_Advisors, max_num=4, extra=4, exclude=('startup', 'id'))

then

```
    advisors_item_formset = AdvisorsFormSet(
        request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='advisors',
        queryset=S_Advisors.objects.filter(startup=startup))
```

how do I add a placeholder text in each form field generated when I render the formset forms in the template?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean initial values for the fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modelformset_factory takes a `form` keyword argument.

So if you create a ModelForm

```
class AdvisorForm( forms.ModelForm ):
  class Meta:
    model=Advisor

  def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
    super( AdvisorForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
    self.fields[ 'name' ].widget.attrs[ 'placeholder' ]="Enter name"
```

you can pass it to modelformset_factory

```
AdvisorFormSet=modelformset_factory( Advisor, form=AdvisorForm )
```